# Android bluetooth read string

Tags: android-bluetooth

Currently my android bluetooth device receive character one by one. Is it possible for me to receive one shot together without one by one ? Thanks for advice.

For example incoming data:
abcd but incoming one by 1 like a b c d

how to make it like:
abcd incoming abcd straight away.

I need to change this line code?

```
message = txtReceived.getText().toString() + (char)data;}
```

This is my current code.

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);


int delay = 1000;   // delay in ms
int period = 100;   // repeat in ms

timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
    public void run()
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            final byte data = read();

            readMessageHandler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    String message;

                    if (data != 1){
                        /*  if(txtReceived.getText().toString().equals("ON") || txtReceived.getText().toString().equals("OFF"))
                        {
                            txtReceived.setText("");
                        }*/
                        message = txtReceived.getText().toString() + (char)data;}

                    else{
                        message = "";}

                    txtReceived.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}, delay, period);

private byte read()
{

    byte dataRead = 0;


    try
    {
        dataRead = (byte) inputStream.read();
    }
    catch(IOException readException)
    {
        toastText = "Failed to read from input stream: " + readException.getMessage();
        Toast.makeText(Blood_Pressure.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return dataRead;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `inputstream.read` returns only one byte of data, hence, you are reading `byte-by-byte`.

You can send the size of message before the message and then send the message.
You can modify the code to something like this.

```
{
...
// assuming size is within the range of integer
byte[] sizeOfIncomingData = new byte[4];
inputStream.read(sizeOfIncomingdata, 0, 4);

int size = getIntFromByteArray(sizeOfIncomingData);
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[size];
inputStream.read(dataBuffer, 0, size);
String message = new String(dataBuffer, "UTF-8");
}

private int getIntFromByteArray(byte[] bytes)
{
    return (bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 24 | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[3] & 0xFF);
}
```